# Dart List min/max value

Tags: dart

How do you get the min and max values of a List in Dart.

```dart
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].min //returns 1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].max //returns 5
```

I'm sure I could *a)* write a short function or *b)* copy then sort the list and select the last value,

but I'm looking to see if there is a more native solution if there is any.

Answer (score 251, accepted):

Assuming the list is not empty you can use [Iterable.reduce](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.3/dart-core/Iterable/reduce.html) :

```dart
import 'dart:math';

main(){
  print([1,2,8,6].reduce(max)); // 8
  print([1,2,8,6].reduce(min)); // 1
}
```

Comment: What do I do if the list can be empty? Is there a way to avoid checking for emptiness?

Comment: You can do `[maxOnEmpty, ...list].reduce(max)`.

Comment: Thanks, but I already found out the cleaner solution. `[1,2,8,6].fold(0, max)` will do the trick.

Comment: Seems like this still doesn't work on an empty list... E.g. `[].fold(0, max)` throws an error. @AlexSemeniuk

Comment: @PROgram52bc Have you specified the list type correctly?

Comment: @AlexSemeniuk your solution perfect: `int biggestNum(List<int> numbers) => numbers.fold(0, max);`

Answer (score 71):

If you don't want to import `dart: math` and still wants to use `reduce`:

```
main() {
  List list = [2,8,1,6]; // List should not be empty.
  print(list.reduce((curr, next) => curr > next? curr: next)); // 8 --> Max
  print(list.reduce((curr, next) => curr < next? curr: next)); // 1 --> Min
}
```

Comment: Why would one seriously prefer this approach?

Comment: @MateusFelipe You can pass this as a Function, where as with math.max or min I ran into some trouble.

Comment: Well, then it would be a good idea providing the specific use-case of your approach, as it seems to be a very edge case.

Comment: This actually is a useful comment. Whenever the list is List of Objects rather than List of (String, Number) we can't directly use dart:math. We have to do something like "curr.id < next.id" etc.

Comment: Exactly, it is totally useful. For example, I used this for DateTime: `dates.reduce((current, next) => current.compareTo(next) > 0 ? current : next)`  Closest thing to LINQ-like syntax.

Comment: @KavindaJayakody You can do this using myList.map((e) => e.myNumber).reduce(max)

Comment: This answers provides the most flexible and clear solution to the problem. It's also a great use of the .reduce paradigm.

Comment: @KavindaJayakody For a list of objects I'd suggest [`minBy()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/minBy.html)/[`maxBy()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/maxBy.html) from [collection package](https://pub.dev/packages/collection).

Comment: @kozenka Nice. You should put that as one of the answers.

Answer (score 38):

You can now achieve this with [an `extension` as of Dart 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58288266/6509751):

```dart
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].min; // returns 1
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].max; // returns 5
}

extension FancyIterable on Iterable<int> {
  int get max => reduce(math.max);

  int get min => reduce(math.min);
}
```

Comment: wonderful, add `as` keyword at import statement works for me. `import 'dart:math' as math;`.

Answer (score 11):

An example to get Min/Max value using **reduce** based on condition for a list of Map objects

```
Map studentA = {
  'Name': 'John',
  'Marks': 85
};

Map studentB = {
  'Name': 'Peter',
  'Marks': 70
};

List<Map> students = [studentA, studentB];

// Get student having maximum mark from the list

Map studentWithMaxMarks = students.reduce((a, b) {
    if (a["Marks"] > b["Marks"])
        return a;
    else
        return b;
});


// Get student having minimum mark from the list (one liner)

Map studentWithMinMarks = students.reduce((a, b) => a["Marks"] < b["Marks"] ? a : b);
```

Another example to get Min/Max value using **reduce** based on condition for a list of class objects

```
class Student {
    final String Name;
    final int Marks;

    Student(this.Name, this.Marks);
}

final studentA = Student('John', 85);
final studentB = Student('Peter', 70);

List<Student> students = [studentA, studentB];

// Get student having minimum marks from the list

Student studentWithMinMarks = students.reduce((a, b) => a.Marks < b.Marks ? a : b);
```

Answer (score 7):

If your list is empty, `reduce` will throw an error.

You can use `fold` instead of `reduce`.

```dart
// nan compare to any number will return false
final initialValue = number.nan;
// max
values.fold(initialValue, (previousValue, element) => element.value > previousValue ? element.value : previousValue);
// min
values.fold(initialValue, (previousValue, element) => element.value < previousValue ? element.value : previousValue);
```

It can also use to calculate sum.

```
final initialValue = 0;
values.fold(initialValue, (previousValue, element) => element.value + previousValue);
```

Although `fold` is not cleaner than `reduce` for getting min/max, it is still a powerful method to do more flexible actions.

Answer (score 3):

For empty lists: This will return 0 if list is empty, the max value otherwise.

```
  List<int> x = [ ];  
  print(x.isEmpty ? 0 : x.reduce(max)); //prints 0

  List<int> x = [1,32,5];  
  print(x.isEmpty ? 0 : x.reduce(max)); //prints 32
```

Answer (score 3):

```
void main() {
  firstNonConsecutive([1,2,3,4,6,7,8]);
}

int? firstNonConsecutive(List<int> arr) {
  var max = arr.reduce((curr, next) => curr > next? curr: next);
  print(max); // 8 --> Max
  var min = arr.reduce((curr, next) => curr < next? curr: next);
  print(min); // 1 --> Min
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int minF() {
  final mass = [1, 2, 0, 3, 5];
  mass.sort();
  
  return mass[0];
}
```

Comment: You could also use the list.first or list.last property to achieve a min and max without using the index.

Comment: Note that the time complexity of a sort is generally `O(n log n)` whereas min and max are `O(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a more sophisticated min/max, such as finding an object with a min/max of a field, or use of a comparison predicate, use [`minBy()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/minBy.html) and [`maxBy()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/maxBy.html) from the [collection package](https://pub.dev/packages/collection):

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

class Person {
  final String name;
  final int age;
  
  Person(this.name, this.age);
  
  @override
  String toString() => '$name (age $age)';
}

main() {
  final alice = Person('Alice', 30);
  final bob = Person('Bob', 40);
  final chris = Person('Chris', 25);
  final dan = Person('Dan', 35);
  
  final people = [alice, bob, chris, dan];
  
  print('Youngest is ${minBy(people, (e) => e.age)}');
  print('Oldest is ${maxBy(people, (e) => e.age)}');
  print('First alphabetically is ${minBy(people, (e) => e.name)}');
  print('Last alphabetically is ${maxBy(people, (e) => e.name)}');
  
  print('Largest name length times age is ${maxBy(people, (e) => e, compare: (a, b) => (a.name.length * a.age).compareTo(b.name.length * b.age))}');
}
```

Output:

```
Youngest is Chris (age 25)
Oldest is Bob (age 40)
First alphabetically is Alice (age 30)
Last alphabetically is Dan (age 35)
Largest name length times age is Alice (age 30)
```

Comment: Nice. This method is more straightforward.

Comment: What if collection has several objects with same max/min and I need all of this objects?

Comment: @ivanesi I'm afraid I don't fully understand. Can you provide more detail? Or, consider creating a new question with your details and feel free to tag me on it.