# What is the smartest way to find the larger / smaller of two numbers

Tags: dart

In search of the smartest, most efficient and readable way to do the below:

```
int one = 1, two = 2;
int larger = one < two?two:one;
```

I prefer(or a variadic version of the below):

```
int largest(one,two){return one<two?two:one;}
int larger = largest(one,two);
```

But dart has no inline or macro.

With List:

```
var nums = [51,4,6,8];
nums.sort();
in largest = nums.last
```

Or(Thank you,  Günter Zöchbauer):

```
print([1,2,8,6].reduce(max));
```

Using math library:

```
import 'dart:math';
int largest = max(21,56);
```

Probably the best, but how efficient is max in comparison to the first approach?

Why the question? 
With the first approach I must check comparisons are done right for each of them;hundreds of them sometimes. With the second, only one function to verify, but hundreds of function calls.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490868/dart-list-min-max-value/20490970#20490970

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I'm pretty sure just

```
import 'dart:math';
int largest = max(21,56);
```

is the best way. It is small enough to be inlined by a compiler (dart2js, VM) and it is the least surprise for the reader. For a custom implementation the reader had to investigate the function to be sure about what it does.

For collections of values I find this the most elegant way

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20490970/217408

```
import 'dart:math';

main(){
  print([1,2,8,6].reduce(max)); // 8
  print([1,2,8,6].reduce(min)); // 1
}
```

Reordering a list just to get the min/max is quite inefficient

```
var nums = [51,4,6,8];
nums.sort();
in largest = nums.last
```

Comment: Only caveat is that `min` and `max` from `dart:math` are only defined on numbers. They are pretty efficient on those, considering that they handle `min(0.0, -0.0)` -> -0.0 and returns NaN if either value is NaN. I doubt they are as quick as `a<b?a:b`, but in practice it's not something I would optimize until I was sure it was a bottleneck for my program.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use `max` getter from `IterableIntegerExtension` of `collection` package.

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

final nums = [1,2,3];
final max = nums.max;
```