# How to retrieve the minimum and maximum values of int and double in Dart?

Tags: dart

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on a Dart project, and I need to obtain the minimum and maximum values for the `int` and `double` data types. I'm aware that Dart doesn't provide specific constants like `int.MIN_VALUE` or `double.MAX_VALUE` as some other languages do.

I would appreciate it if someone could guide me on how to retrieve these values correctly in Dart. What is the recommended approach to obtain the maximum and minimum values for `int` and `double`?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dart List min/max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490868/dart-list-min-max-value)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50429660/is-there-a-constant-for-max-min-int-double-value-in-dart

Comment: @Craicerjack Thank you, But It's not my answer. I'm talking about data types like `int` or `double` not the `Iterable` types.

Comment: Do you mean in use throughout your application or how are you comparing these datatypes for there to be a min or a max?

Answer (score -1):

Minimum & maximum value of list in dart

```
// Creating a  list
var list = [121, 12, 33, 14, 2, 3, 1.5, -1];

// Sorting the list
list.sort();

// Printing the values
debugPrint("Smallest value in the list : ${list.first}");
debugPrint("Largest value in the list : ${list.last}");
```

Output:

```
Smallest value in the list : -1
Largest value in the list : 121
```

Comment: This does not answer OPs question.